# How can I get token response with username and password textfields? dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authorization, token, rest

I'm kind of new to `rest api` and `flutter`.
I wanna login with the username and password and get the token response.
How can I get the username and password from the text field for `authorization`?
I'm also not sure about the auth code is correct?

```
imports

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final  usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final  passwordController = TextEditingController();

Future<String> authorization() async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse('url'));
    request.fields.addAll({
      'grant_type': 'info',
      'client_id': 'info',
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
    });

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> auth =
          jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());

      return auth['access_token'];
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  void _setText() {
    setState(() {
      username = usernameController.text;
      password = passwordController.text;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'username'),
              controller: usernameController,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'password'),
              controller: passwordController,
            ),
          ),          
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: _setText,
            child: Text('Login'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: At first use `usernameController.text.trim()` also for `passwordController`, then use `http` package to send request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you are using TextEditingControllers, you won't have to use Strings to hold the values of username and password.

change them like this:

```
  TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController  passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

Then, change your API post to this:

```
Future<String> authorization() async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse('url'));
    request.fields.addAll({
      'grant_type': 'info',
      'client_id': 'info',
      'username': usernameController.text, //notice you have to use .text
      'password': passwordController.text, //notice you have to use .text
    });
```

- Your `onPressed` like this:

  ```
  RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
  String token = await authorization();
  print(token); //This will be your token.
  },
  child: Text('Login'),),
  ```
- you don't need this anymore:

  ```
  //void _setText() {
  //setState(() {
  //username = usernameController.text;
  // password = passwordController.text;
  //});
  //}
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. When I implement your offers it gives just `flutter:   ` on terminal. I can't be authorized, what should be done?

Comment: Did you enable email sign up in sign in methods in firebase console? Please double check that. This is most likely the cause. Post the exact error that you get.

Comment: Hi. I don't use firebase. There is an endpoint which is created on another test server and I'm trying to trade with it. I have to connect and list and edit the data.

Comment: If you aren't authenticating, it means that you are communicating with your server. What is the response.status code ? If you have a response, that means your problem isn't in flutter

Comment: I tried in postman. it's "error": "invalid_scope" and 400 Bad Request. I don't have response on terminal

Comment: If postman is giving 400 bad request, then the problem is definitely not in flutter. Check your url again, and your parameters or share them here. But use the code posted above for flutter.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I'm going to ask the accuracy of this information to those who prepare then.

Comment: If you want, we can take a look at it if it's a sandbox or nothing confidential. You shouldn't ask other people to check their wok before you are sure that it's not your problem.

Comment: Hi. The problem is solved. Can I ask you other questions about this subject or should I open another title?

Comment: Great, happy to hear that! Of course you can ask questions, but please post it to a separate thread and I or whoever is available will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should change a bit your methods to gives the parameters to you function `authorization` that will call your API :

```
  // Add parameters
  Future<String> authorization(username,password) async {
      ...
  }

  void _setText() {
    // This will call your API with the form parameters
    result = await authorization(usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
    // result should have your token (= the response from the API)
  }
```